# Get Http Status Code with OkHttp

Tags: java, http-status-codes, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp to get the content of some websites.

However, I'm not able to get the Http-Status Code from the response.

My Java-Code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://www.google.at")
                    .build();
Response httpResponse = client.newCall(request).execute();    
String html = httpResponse.body().string();
```

This method:

```
httpResponse.toString();
```

Returns the following content:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://www.google.at}
```

Is there a way to get the statusCode as an integer, or do I need a Regular Expression to filter it out of this toString()-method?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use [HttpResponse](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true) class and using that you can access the status code as follows;

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

If you are using com.squareup.okhttp.Response then you can use the code() method to get the HTTP status code.

```
Response httpResponse = client.newCall(request).execute(); 
httpResponse.code();
```

Comment: The execute-function returns an `com.squareup.okhttp.Response`-object, not an `org.apache.http.HttpResponse` object

Comment: There is a method called code(http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Response.html#code()) within the class you just mentioned. Are you not able to use that?

Answer (score 40):

You can get response with:

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

And get response status code with:

```
int responseCode = response.code();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
HttpStatus status = response!=null ? HttpStatus.resolve(response.code()) : null;
```